# Extracting data from a CSV file in C++

Tags: c++, csv

The content of my test csv file looks as follows:

```
    *test.csv*

    name;age;weight;height;test
    Bla;32;1.2;4.3;True
    Foo;43;2.2;5.3;False
    Bar;None;3.8;2.4;True
    Ufo;32;1.5;5.4;True
```

I load the `test.csv` file with the following C++ program that prints the file's content on the screen:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

void readCSV(std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > &data, std::string filename);
void printCSV(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> &data);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string file_path = "./test.csv";
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > data;
    readCSV(data, file_path);
    printCSV(data);
    return 0;
}

void readCSV(std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > &data, std::string filename) {
    char delimiter = ';';
    std::string line;
    std::string item;
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::vector<std::string> row;
        std::stringstream string_stream(line);
        while (std::getline(string_stream, item, delimiter)) {
            row.push_back(item);
        }
        data.push_back(row);
    }
    file.close();
}

void printCSV(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > &data) {
    for (std::vector<std::string> row: data) {
        for (std::string item: row) {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I have the following questions:

- How can I load only rows where, for example, `age == 32`?
- How can I load, for example, only the `name`, `weight` columns?
- How can I exclude rows that contain `None`?
- How can I skip the first row of the document?

Does it make more sense to extract the desired information after I loaded the entire csv file (if memory is not a problem)? If possible, I want to use only the STL.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have three decent questions here, each should get their own question. The forth question is simple. Use `std::getline` to read the first line and then simply do nothing with it.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the advice. I'll close the question and ask three new ones.

Answer (score 1):

you can try some csv libraries, but if you want to do this with custom code then

Inside `printCSV` you ask the `cin` to enter column names

Maintain it in a variable

In this code `for (std::vector<std::string> row: data)`

Check the `item` again each of those input when first the loop runs

then inside the second loop keep an index, accordingly you skip the column number

Example code to print only two columns

```
void printCSV(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > &data) {
    int col = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> column_filter;
    std::vector<int> column_index;
    column_filter.push_back("name");
    column_filter.push_back("weight");
    int row1 =0;

    for (std::vector<std::string> row: data) {
        col = 0;
        if(row1==0) {
            int col1 = 0;
            for (std::string item: row) {
                for (std::string colname: column_filter){
                    if(item.compare(colname)==0) {
                        column_index.push_back(col1);
                    }
                }
                col1++;
            }

        }

        for (std::string item: row) {
            int found =0;
            for (int index: column_index) {
                if(index==col) found = 1;
            }
            if(found==1)
            std::cout << item << ' ';
            col++;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        row1++;
    }
}
```

Output

```
name weight 
Bla 1.2 
Foo 2.2 
Bar 3.8 
Ufo 1.5
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, as suggested by another user, I am going to close the question and split it into three different questions. You may answer one of these.

Answer (score 1):

Before you close. Here all answers in one file. But I will then explain in your single questions then later.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// Save typing Work
using Rec = std::vector<std::string>;
std::regex delimiter{ ";" };

// Proxy class for easier input and output
struct Record {
    // Our data for one record
    Rec data{};

    // Overwrite extractor operator
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Record& r) {
        // Read on complete line from the input stream, and check, if the read was successfull
        if (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line)) {

            // If there is something in our data vector already, delete it
            r.data.clear();
            // Now, in one statement, split the string into tokens and copy the result into our data vector
            std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), delimiter, -1), {}, std::back_inserter(r.data));
        }
        return is;
    }

    // Overwrite inserter for easier output
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Record& r) {
        std::copy(r.data.begin(), r.data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os,"\t"));
        return os;
    }
};

// Proxy for the complete CSV file
struct Roster {
    // The header
    Rec header{};
    // All records of the CSV file
    std::vector<Record> records{};

    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Roster& r) {
        // Read on complete line from the input stream, and check, if the read was successfull
        if (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line)) {
            // So, we just have read the header
            // Now, in one statement, split the string into tokens and copy the result into the header
            r.header.clear();
            std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), delimiter, -1), {}, std::back_inserter(r.header));

            // Now, in one statement, read all lines, split the string into tokens and copy the result into our record vector
            r.records.clear();
            std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Record>(is), {}, std::back_inserter(r.records));
        }
        return is;
    }

    // Overwrite inserter for easier output
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Roster& r) {
        std::copy(r.records.begin(), r.records.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Record>(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }
};

int main() {

    // Open CSV file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream csvFileStream("r:\\test.csv"); csvFileStream) {

        Roster roster{}; 

        // Read the complete CSV file
        csvFileStream >> roster;

        // Show all read data on std::cout
        std::cout << roster;

        // All records with age ==32
        std::cout << "\n\nAge 32\n";
        std::vector<Record> age32{};
        std::copy_if(roster.records.begin(), roster.records.end(), std::back_inserter(age32), [](const Record& r) { return r.data[1] == "32"; });
        for (const Record& r : age32) std::cout << r << "\n";

        // Or
        std::cout << "\n\nAge 32   Option 2\n";
        csvFileStream.clear(); csvFileStream.seekg(std::ios::beg); age32.clear();
        std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<Record>(csvFileStream), {}, std::back_inserter(age32), [](const Record& r) { return r.data[1] == "32"; });
        for (const Record& r : age32) std::cout << r << "\n";

        // Get Name and weight columns
        std::cout << "\n\nweight and columns\n";
        std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> nameAndWeight{};
        std::transform(roster.records.begin(), roster.records.end(), std::back_inserter(nameAndWeight), 
            [](const Record& r) { std::vector<std::string>rec{ r.data[0], r.data[2] } ; return rec; });

        for (const std::vector<std::string>& r : nameAndWeight) std::cout << r[0] << "\t" << r[1] << "\n";

        // Everything but none
        std::cout << "\n\nEverything but none\n";
        std::vector<Record> notNone{};
        std::copy_if(roster.records.begin(), roster.records.end(), std::back_inserter(notNone), [](const Record& r) { return r.data[1] != "None"; });
        for (const Record& r : notNone) std::cout << r << "\n";

    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open source file\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```